# Analyzing the time complexity of Coin changing

Tags: dynamic-programming

We're doing the classic problem of determining the number of ways that we can make change that amounts to Z given a set of coins.

For example, Amount=5 and Coins={1, 2, 3}. One way we can make 5 is {2, 3}.

The naive recursive solution has a time complexity of factorial time.

> f(n) = n * f(n-1) = n!

My professor argued that it actually has a time complexity of `O(2^n)`, because we only choose to use a coin or not. That intuitively makes sense. However how come my recurence doesn't work out to be `O(2^n)`?

**EDIT:**

My recurrence is as follows:

```
   f(5, {1, 2, 3})
     /           \                     .....
f(4, {2, 3})  f(3, {1, 3})        .....
```

Notice how the branching factor decreases by 1 at every step.

Formally.

> T(n) = n*F(n-1) = n!

Comment: Well, what is the justification for O(n!)?

Comment: Hey Oliver, Just updated the question.

Comment: You can think of the recurrence as follows: for each element `i` it either includes that element in the solution or not. So there's essentially two branches per element and there are `n` elements.

Comment: That's what my professor told me. But there are at most |C| branches at each level.

Comment: @unknown what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: @unknown the algorithm you show is solving the same subproblem repeatedly: you can get {3} from {1,2,3} by (i) first removing 1 and then 2 as well as by (ii) first removing 2 and then 1. If you use memoization it considers each subset precisely once; there are 2^n subsets.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence doesn't work out to what you expect it to work out to because it doesn't reflect the number of operations made by the algorithm.

If the algorithm decides for each coin whether to output it or not, then you can model its time complexity with the recurrence `T(n) = 2*T(n-1) + O(1)` with `T(1)=O(1)`; the intuition is that for each coin you have two options---output the coin or not; this obviously solves to `T(n)=O(2^n)`.

Comment: But you can have combinations like {1,1,1,1,1} for a target of 5. This isn't a matter of whether to choose 1 or not, is it? 2^n corresponds to the complexity of finding a powerset. Even if you found a powerset of the coin denominations, you don't cover all possible combinations in the solution.

Comment: @ArxoClay it is. You just have to treat each `1` as a separate element of the set. I'm assuming here that you have finitely many copies of each coin (e.g. two 1's, a single 2 and a pair of 3's, in which case your set of coins would be {1,1,2,3,3}).

Comment: So given k denominations and for a target value of n, the complexity should be O(k ^n) for a single combination, but you could have multiple such combinations, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I too was trying to analyze the time complexity for the brute force which performs depth first search:

```py
def countCombinations(coins, n, amount, k=0):
    if amount == 0:
        return 1
    res = 0
    for i in range(k, n):
        if coins[k] <= amount:
            remaining_amount = amount - coins[i]     # considering this coin, try for remaining sum 
            # in next round include this coin too
            res += countCombinations(coins, n, remaining_amount, i)
    return res
```

but we can see that the coins which are used in one round is used again in the next round, so at least for 1st coin we have n items at each stage which is equivalent to permutation with repetition n^r for n items available to arrange into r positions at each stage.

ex: [1, 1, 1, 1]; sum = 4

This will generate a recursive tree where for first path we literally have solutions at each diverged subpath until we have the sum=0. so the time complexity is O(sum^n) ie for each stage in the path towards sum we have n different subpaths.

Note however there is another algorithm which uses take/not-take approach and at most there is 2 branch at a node in recursion tree. Hence the time complexity for this algorithm is O(2^(n*m))
ex: say coins = [1, 1] sum = 2 there are 11 nodes/points to visit in the recursion tree for 6 paths(leaves) then complexity is at most 2^(2*2) => 2^4 => 16 (Hence 11 nodes visiting for a max of 16 possibility is correct but little loose on upper bound).

```py
def get_count(coins, n, sum):
    if(n == 0):    # no coins left, to try a combination that matches the sum
        return 0
    if(sum == 0):  # no more sum left to match, means that we have completely co-incided with our trial
        return 1   # (return success)
    # don't-include the last coin in the sum calc so, leave it and try rest
    excluded = get_count(coins, n-1, sum)
    included = 0
    if(coins[n-1] <= sum):
        # include the last coin in the sum calc, so reduce by its quantity in the sum
        # we assume here that n is constant ie, it is supplied in unlimited(we can choose same coin again and again),
        included = get_count(coins, n, sum-coins[n-1])
    return included+excluded
```